# how to display a folder in R

Tags: r, shell, directory

I tried to display a folder using R script. I know commands like `file.choose()` and `file.show()` but I would like to run an `R` script to display the folder (a real folder, not the picture nor a screenshot of it). After display the folder, the script is done. I'd like to be able to choose to open any file in the folder but won't import anything into `R`.

file.show() will display a exactly file but I would like to display a folder. Maybe I can say what I am looking for is folder.show() or dictionary.show()??
file.choose() will import that file to R but I do not want to import anything into R
Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what "a real folder" means in this case. A directory listing? A file open dialog box where you can browse the file system?

Comment: Your description sounds like what `file.choose()` does... What exactly do you want that is different from it?

Comment: @Molx file.choose() will import the file into R. I do not want that. I only want to display that folder, no file choose.

Comment: @MikeWise what I mean is a file open dialog box where you can browse the file system. Similar to file.show() but file show only show me a file. I would like to show me a folder.

Comment: `file.choose()` does not import the file into R. It returns the file's path, but you can always click Cancel or simply ignore whatever it returns. If you don't want the path to be printed, just use `invisible(file.choose())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ( if OS=windows)

```
shell("explorer C:\\Users\\xxx\\yy", intern=TRUE)
```

Comment: LOL. It works. Thank you! Could you do me a favor? Could you explain how this command works to me? what does "explorer" do? What does "intern" mean here?

Comment: If this is the solution you're looking for, then you didn't ask the question properly. What you wanted is not to display a folder from R, you want to open the Windows Explorer, since the window won't be connected to R in any way. It means you're probably using R for something very odd.

Comment: @Molx I know I use R for something very odd. That is why I ask question here. But still thank you very much for explaining that for me. Really appreciate